# How is the level of quests determined?

Tags: castle-cats

Before the 1.6.3 update of Castle Cats, the level of the quest was based on the activate cats. For example, if you had only level 10 cats, you'd get mostly high leveled quests. With a couple of lower cats, you'd had some lower leveled quests to match their strength.

However, after the update, every cat can be chosen to go on a quest (instead of only the active ones). How is now the level of quests determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit (6 November 2017)**. After an update, you are able to set the desired quest level yourself. Active kittens do nothing, except being 'favored' in showing on the main screen of your guild.

After testing different things, I can confirm it is still the cats that are active. So, having higher leveled cats as active makes the quests higher level.

The restrictions that only active cats can be sent on missions has been removed since the update.